# BlackBerry product.dll is missing error

Tags: blackberry

I have a new BlackBerry 9630.
I downloaded [this software](https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/contactFormPreload.do?code=A8BAA56554F96369AB93E4F3BB068C22&dl=16D92CE0938A8CAB5DBA35836C016D04) for it.

When I click on the newly installed "Desktop Manager", I get this error:

```
---------------------------
DesktopMgr.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The program can't start because product.dll is missing from your computer.
Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

If I manually search for that file across my entire C:\ drive, it is not there.

I am using Windows 7.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the software I was installing.

I uninstalled that software and used the CD that came with the BlackBerry, and that worked fine.

I believe what I installed may be found [on this page](https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=A8BAA56554F96369AB93E4F3BB068C22) if you select the "BlackBerry Desktop Software 5.0" item from the drop-down.  Since I installed it from the CD, I can't be 100% sure that this is the same as what I used, but it seems likely.

After installing, you can check for updates and get the service pack from within the application, so there is no need to download the service pack separately from that site.